# ¿Como puedo interpretar esto en C#?

Tags: c#

Tengo esta linea de código:

```
str[i] = str[i] + 3;  //Esto es código C/C++
```

Ahora bien, esto me marca error si lo corro en C#, he aquí mi pregunta, como podría interpretar esto en C#?
Esto es un equivalente a:

> mivariable = mivariable+10

He intentado hacerlo de este modo:

> str[i] += 3;

Pero tampoco me funciona, espero puedan ayudarme a lo que intento lograr, si lo estoy haciendo mal agradecería sus comentarios o respuestas.

Comment: Así lo declaro: char[] str = new char[1000];     El error que me marca es: cannot implicitly convert type 'int ' to 'char'

Comment: el codigo en c tambien lo declaras igual

Comment: @EduardoJaramilloLicea Sí, lo que quiero lograr es interpretar lo ya mencionado en C#

Answer (score 2):

Si estas sumando `3` a un char quiere decir que estas trabajando con el valor `ascii` de ese caracter para cambiarlo, no es que quieres sumar un valor numerico a esa posicion del array

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        char[] str = new char[2]; 
        str[0] = 'A';
        str[1] = 'B';
        
        //en una sola linea
        //
        str[0] = (char)(((int)str[0]) + 3);
        
        // en varias lineas
        //
        int asciiCode = (int)str[1];
        asciiCode += 3;
        str[1] = (char)asciiCode;
        
        Console.WriteLine("Result= [0]:{0}, [1]:{1}", str[0], str[1]);
    }
}
```

Como observaras teniendo los caracteres `A` y `B`, puedes sumarle el valor `3` generando el corrimiento del caracter `ascii`, pero para eso debes convertir el `char` a `int`, sumar y luego volver a convertir el `int` a `char`